# How to show one tableview data in two segments in swift

Tags: swift, segment

I am using [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) for segment

i want to show one tableview data in two segment with sorted, for that i am using below code

SegmentViewController code: if i add `child_2.isSorted = false` then error

> Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'isSorted'

```
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip

class SegmentViewController: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var testSeg: ButtonBarView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // change selected bar color
    // Sets the background colour of the pager strip and the pager strip item
        settings.style.buttonBarBackgroundColor = .white
        settings.style.buttonBarItemBackgroundColor = .yellow

        // Sets the pager strip item font and font color
        settings.style.buttonBarItemFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 15.0)!
        settings.style.buttonBarItemTitleColor = .gray

        changeCurrentIndexProgressive = { [weak self] (oldCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, newCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, progressPercentage: CGFloat, changeCurrentIndex: Bool, animated: Bool) -> Void in
              guard changeCurrentIndex == true else { return }
              oldCell?.label.textColor = .gray
              newCell?.label.textColor = .blue
        }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    }
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.buttonBarView.frame = testSeg.frame
    }
override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
let child_1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SegTableViewController")
let child_2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SegTableViewController")
    child_2.isSorted = false

return [child_1, child_2]
    
    
}        
}
```

SegTableViewController code: here in both segments showing only `sortedArray` i need in first segment `sortedArray` and second segment `namesArray`.. how to do that.. could anyone please suggest me

```
 import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip
class SegTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, IndicatorInfoProvider {

var sortedArray = [String]()
var isSorted = true

func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
    
    if isSorted{
        return IndicatorInfo(title: "Sorted")

    }else{
    return IndicatorInfo(title: "Normal")
    }

}
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var namesArray = ["afsdf","ddsfsdf", "hjhgjh", "trytryr", "nvbmvnb", "yuertyri", "bmvmncb", "jgfhk", "ytuioi", "sdfgsfdsh", "mkhjgijik", "gfuyru"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     sortedArray = namesArray.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending }
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isSorted {
       return sortedArray.count
    }
    else{
    return namesArray.count
}
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! UITableViewCell
    
    if isSorted{
    cell.textLabel?.text = sortedArray[indexPath.row]

    }
    else{
        cell.textLabel?.text = namesArray[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast your view controller like this

```
override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
    let child_1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SegTableViewController")
    let child_2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SegTableViewController")
    (child_2 as? SegTableViewController).isSorted = false
    return [child_1, child_2]
}
```

Also, no need for an array for displaying data. Use only one array `namesArray` like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if isSorted {
        namesArray = namesArray.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending }
    }
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    
}
```